# OpenCV Java(3.4.4) Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type()) in function 'void cv::gem()'

Tags: java, android, opencv

I got this Error message when I tried to multiply 2 Matrix by using Core.gemm() function in my program

`OpenCV(3.4.4) Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type()) in void cv::gemm(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, double, cv::InputArray, double, cv::OutputArray, int), file /build/3_4-contrib_pack-contrib-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 1558`

This is my code:

```
 Mat A = new Mat(); //receive 3*3 Matrix
 Mat A1 = new Mat();
 Core.invert(A,A1); //convert Mat A to inverse Mat A
 Mat B = new Mat(); //receive 1*3 Matrix
 Mat C = new Mat(); //receive 1*3 Matrix
 Mat D = new Mat(); //receive 3*3 Matrix
 Mat D1 = new Mat();
 Core.invert(D,D1); //convert Mat D to inverse Mat D
 Mat E = new Mat(); //receive 3*3 Matrix
 Mat dest1 = new Mat();
 Mat dest2 = new Mat();
 Mat dest3 = new Mat();
 Mat my_answer = new Mat(); //the answer shold be 1*3 or 3*1 Matrix
 Core.gemm(E,C,1,Dummy_Null,0,dest1); //multiply function ps.Dummy_Null is my 3*3 Matrix with 0
 Core.gemm(dest1.t(),D1,1,Dummy_Null,0,dest2); // multiply function
 Core.subtract(dest2,B,dest3);
 Core.gemm(A1,dest3,1,Dummy_Null,0,my_answer);//<------I got error from this line
 //print my_answer to my log//
```

I was try to figure it out but I ran out of an idea. I try to find solution from several forum that relate to this problem but again I cannot find any solution that can help. somebody help me please!

ps. I use

```
CvType.CV_64F
```

Comment: Your matrices are uninitialized and `Dummy_Null` is undefined. Please fix your code sample.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a minimal but complete and reproducible example code. Please read [ask].